# How to call API every 2 seconds until desired result or timeout in async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I need to call an api to get a status every 2 seconds if the response is `running` and first return when response is either `complete` or `failed`, or until 30 seconds have passed and the function times out.

This is what I have now which works, but I am sure it can be done much more efficient, but I simply can't figure it out at this point:

```
const getStatus = async (processId) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`example.com/api/getStatus/${processId}`);
    const status = await response.json();

    return await status;
  } catch(err) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Inside another async function using getStatus():

```
randomFunction = async () => {
  let status = null;
  let tries = 0;
  let stop = false;

  while (tries <= 15 && !stop) {
    try {
      status = await getStatus('some-process-id');

      if (status === 'complete') {
        stop = true;
        // do something outside of loop
      }

      if (status === 'failed') {
        stop = true;
        throw Error(status);
      }

      if (tries === 15) {
        stop = true;
        throw Error('Request timed out');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // handle error
    }

    const delay = time => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), time));

    if (tries < 15) {
      await delay(2000);
    }

    tries++;
  }
}
```

I would prefer to handle the looping inside `getStatus()` and in a more readable format, but is it possible?

**EDIT:**
I tried a solution that looks better and seems to work as I expect, see it here:

https://gist.github.com/AntonBramsen/6cec0faade032dfa3c175b7d291e07bd

Let me know if parts of the solution contains any solutions that are bad practice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This use case would be a good fit for using Observables - there is a bit of a learning curve, but it is ideally suited to this kind of problem.

Comment: Don't use `return await` - `return status` is enough, `status` is not a promise

Comment: Do you really have `// handle error` in that `catch` block? I was assuming that your function should throw when it encounters a problem or timeout

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I do not have `// handle error` in the catch block, just trying to keep the example as short as possible.

Comment: Then show your actual code, please. How are you handling errors? And why do you want to continue the loop after handling an error, why don't you want to put the `try` block around the `await randomFunction()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is for javascript. Unfortunately I don't drink coffee, I can only give you the code in C#. But I guess you get the gist and can figure out how to translate this into java

Let's do this as a generic function:

You have a function that is called every `TimeSpan`, and you want to stop calling this function whenever the function returns `true`, you want to cancel, whenever some maximum time has passed.

For this maximum time I use a `CancellationToken`, this allows you to cancel processing for more reasons than timeout. For instance, because the operator wants to close the program.

```
TapiResult CallApi<TapiResult> <Func<TapiResult> apiCall,
    Func<TapiResult, bool> stopCriterion,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TapiResult apiResult = apiCall;
    while (!stopCriterion(apiResult))
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Task.Delay(delayTime, cancellationToken).Wait;
        apiResult = apiCall;
    }
    return apiResult;
```

}

- `ApiCall` is the Api function to call. The return value is a `TApiResult`. In your case the `status` is your `TApiResult`
- StopCriterion is a function with input ApiResult and output a boolean that is true when the function must stop. In your case this is when `status` equals `complete` or `failed`
- `CancellationToken` is the `Token` you can get from a `CancellationTokenSource`. Whenever you want the procedure to stop processing, just tell the `CancellationTokenSource`, and the function will stop with a `CancellationException`

Suppose this is your Api:

```
Status MyApiCall(int x, string y) {...}
```

Then the usage is:

```
Timespan maxProcessTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

// tell the cancellationTokenSource to stop processing afer maxProcessTime:
cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(maxProcessTime);

// Start processing
Status resultAfterProcessing = CallApi<Status>(
   () => MyApiCall (3, "Hello World!"),        // The Api function to call repeatedly
                                               // it returns a Status
   (status) => status == complete              // stop criterion: becomes true
            || status == failed,               // when status complete or failed
   cancellationTokenSource.Token);             // get a token from the token source
```

TODO: add try / catch for CancellationException, and process what should be done if the task cancels

The function will stop as soon as the stopCriterion becomes true, or when the CancellationTokenSource cancels. This will automatically be done after `maxTimeOut`. However, if you want to stop earlier, for instance because you want to stop the program:

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```